# vuetify date picker range limit to amount of days

Tags: vue.js, date, datepicker

I would like to know  is there a way, how can I limit selection of days to some external props number. What I'd like to achive here for example is if I pass 10 days then in range I can select no more then 10 days[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHPp1.png)

```
   <v-date-picker
      v-model="date"
      :color="color"
      :range="true"
      :allowed-dates="allowedDates"
    >
      <v-btn text color="primary" @click="menu = false">Cancel</v-btn>
      <v-btn text color="primary" @click="onSubmitDate">OK</v-btn>
    </v-date-picker>
  </v-menu>

...
  data() {
    return {
      date: '',
      menu: false,
    };
  },
methods:{
    allowedDates(date) {
      // Can not select days before today and today
      return new Date(date).valueOf() <= Date.now();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think this may help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58701481/how-to-display-a-fixed-vuetify-v-date-picker-range

Comment: Also, I think the condition you added in the `allowedDates` is not correct, you need to change it to `>=` instead of `<=`.